# How do I stop my window from moving when using vsplit?

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, microsoft-windows

When using `:vsplit` my gvim window jumps to a specific screen location. How do I stop this from happening?

Same thing happens when the second to last split is closed.

I'm using gvim on Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because when vertical splitting the window, vim needs to add a vertical scrollbar, which causes vim to recalculate the visual size and eventually makes vim jump to a different screen location. The current workaround is to `:set guioptions-=r guioptions-=L`

**Update**

As of patch [8.0.1278](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1278), you can also use `:set guioptions+=k` to prevent Vim from resizing, see also the documentation at [`:help 'go-k'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27go-k%27)

Comment: Thank you, works great! `guioptions-=L` seems to be enough for me, I might not have covered all cases though. For anyone wondering `:set guioptions-=r` removes the right hand side scrollbar and `guioptions-=L` removes the left one, which appears when using `:vsplit`.